# Simple Question: how can i know like index.php?xxxxxxx?

Tags: php, url, get, submit, goto

how can i know to make like this "http://www.xxxxx.com/?xxxxxx" (like example of mediafire) or "index.php?xxxxxx" **NOT** like "index.php?action=xxxxxx"

example: index.php?photo will direct to gallery or index.php?about will direct to about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the presence of the `$_GET` variable with `isset`.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['photo'])) {
    echo 'Photos';
}
else if (isset($_GET['about'])) {
    echo 'About';
}
```

This gives "Photos" for `index.php?photo` and "About" for `index.php?about`.

Comment: Thanks, Aether i found this solution.. its possible.

Answer (score 1):

You want `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Comment: can you give me example of that?

Comment: @user `echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Answer (score 0):

`/?value=foo` and `/index.php?value=foo` both are equivalent.

On a page like that, using

```
echo $_GET['value'];
```

will show foo.

You would usually use an if statement to pick up the correct page, or include a file based on that variable (After sanitising it).